# Почему прекращается работа программы?

Tags: c

[image: Скрин прекращения работы программы]

Пишу поле для игры, почему-то после прорисовки верхних границ программа крашится, что не так?

```
    /*
A Game: Who want's to be a billionare
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define WIDTH 60
#define HEIGHT 30

void questions(char *questions[]);
void input(char *answers[4]);
int screen();

int main()
{
    int x, y;
    char name[20];
    int score = 0;
    screen();

   // while (score != 15 || score == -1)
       // questions(*questions);
        //input(*answers);

    return 0;
}

int screen() {
    for (int y = 0; y <= HEIGHT; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
            if (y == 0 || y == HEIGHT) {
                printf("-");
            }
            else if (x == 0 || x == WIDTH) {
                printf("|");
            }
            else {
                printf(" ");
            }
        }
        printf('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А что это вы делаете такое? `printf('\n');`? Вот и получается, что `'\n'` — числовое значение — преобразуется в адрес, к которому явно не разрешено обращение. Вот все и красится.

Comment: перенос строки для обработки всего поля по оси y, чтобы не в одну линию все шло

Comment: А если подумать, а не сразу писать в ruSO? Какие кавычки следует использовать? Простите, конечно, но вы хоть минут 5 размышляли? ***Предупреждения компилятора*** зачем игнорировали?

Comment: увидел ошибку, в двойные надо было взять, благодарю)

Comment: Включите предупреждения в компиляторе и `-Werror`, чтобы код не собирался при наличии таких вопиющих ошибок и предупреждения нельзя было игнорировать.

Comment: а что, С преобразует число в указатель и ограничивается только варнингом? ))))  ну и зачем придумали язык, в котором так легко отстрелить себе обе ноги? )))